# Generate static HTML during build

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

Suppose I have a component `Card` that I can pass some props `title` and `text` to render a card containing the passed data. In another component, say `Home`, I have something like this:

```html
<script setup>
const items = [
  {
      title: "My title",
      text: "My content"
  } // [...] many more items
]
</script>
```

```html
<Card v-for="item in items" :title="item.title" :text="item.text"/>
```

The sole reason for having a `Card` component and the `items` array is to have a more modular structure that allows easier changes.
If I have a non-changing list of const objects for `items`, it would make sense that my `Card` HTML can optionally be generated during build rather than by the client. That would allow a much faster initial page load and less time spent on the main thread when I have many items. Is that possible using vite?

Comment: You're describing SSG, take a look here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/ways-of-using-vue.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing! So, a framework like Nuxt would automatically do that for me?

Comment: No problem. Yes you can configure Nuxt to enable SSG/SSR: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#static-hosting - bare in mind that you'll need to use a static site hosting platform like Netlify to deploy your application.